# If a Ferengi woman is forbidden to speak with a stranger, how is she going to fall in love and meet her future husband?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

In one of the episodes in DS9, Quark's mother was reprimanded for speaking with a stranger. If a Ferengi woman is forbidden to speak with a stranger, how is she going to fall in love and marry given that a relationship has no chance to even start?

Comment: There are examples of this on Earth. Your culture is not the only culture! Marriage means different things, depending where you go.

Comment: Marriage for love isn't even *necessarily* the standard practice today. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_marriage "According to historian Stephanie Coontz, marriages for love and personal reasons began to appear in the 14th century. It began to become popular in the early 17th century."

Comment: Downvoting, because "_What a strange culture_" is not only an opinion-based component of the question (quite forbidden here), but because it is a bit stupid as well, as explained in other great comments. The question itself is very good, aside this, so I'd love to upvote once it is edited and this sentence is removed.

Comment: @trejder: It is *not* forbidden to express an opinion. When we say that "opinion-based" questions are forbidden, what we mean is that we don't allow questions that *seek* opinions.

Comment: trejder , that sentence is removed.

Comment: @ruakh That's why I'm saying about opinion-based component (part) of the question, not about opinion-based question itself. You, user91579631 and everyone else is free to express opinions like that, I'm free to dislike such opinions and downvote questions containing them, right?

Comment: @user91579631 Thank you. Question upvoted as promised. Now, it is really great.

Comment: @trejder: You're free to dislike and downvote, but you're *not* free to claim that something is "quite forbidden here" when in fact it's completely allowed.

Comment: @ruakh Agreed! Sorry for misinterpretation.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

### Falling in love and marrying was not considered typical for a Ferengi

From [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ferengi):

> Marriage, like everything else in Ferengi culture, was a business contract, **signed between the prospective groom and the bride's father**, in which the father leased his daughter to the groom for a set period (usually five years) for an agreed fee, paid on the birth of a son. (DS9: "Doctor Bashir, I Presume")

Therefore, we can see that a Ferengi female was not a party in the contract, but more like the subject of the contract.

And from [Chakoteya](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/514.htm), Quark talks to his brother Rom about his wife Prinadora, and Rom's and Prinadora's child, Nog:

> ROM: I should have told her how I felt.
>
> QUARK: Thank the Nagus that you didn't. Remember what happened with
>   Nog's mother? Yeah, don't want to think about her, do you. Let me
>   refresh your memory. You signed a **standard five year marriage contract**
>   with Prinadora's father because you wanted to have a child. **A simple
>   everyday business deal**. But then you fell in love with your wife and
>   wanted to extend the contract. And you were so in love that you never
>   bothered to read the extension before signing it. So in the end, her
>   father swindled you out of all your money. Prinadora left you for a
>   richer man and you got stuck with Nog. **Hooray for romance.**
>
> ROM: Leeta is not Prinadora.

Emphasis mine. Quark states that the contract is standard, and that it is an everyday business deal. Therefore, we can assume that this description matches a typical Ferengi marriage arrangement.

I believe that the only female that fell in love and married because of love, is Quark's and Rom's mother, [Ishka](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ishka). As we know from the Deep Space 9, she stood against all anti-female regulations and laws in the Ferengi Alliance, up to the point that she was wearing clothes!

**Edit:** 
There is also a small talk between Quark and O'Brien about the results of such marriage policy on Ferenginar in [DS9: Fascination](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/456.htm). It seems (from Quark's perspective and as objective as Quark can be to prove his point) to work pretty well :)

> O'BRIEN: What was I supposed to do? Force her [Keiko] to stay here
>   with me?
>
> QUARK: That would've been a good start. You humans, you never learn.
>   You let your women go out in public, hold jobs, wear clothing, and you
>   wonder why your marriages fall apart.
>
> O'BRIEN: That's your solution, Quark, huh? Treat women like property?
>
> QUARK: Criticise it all you want. But on the Ferengi homeworld,
>   husbands and wives never argue. There's no divorce, no broken homes,
>   nothing but peaceful conjugal bliss.

Comment: Ferengi women falling in love doesn't seem to be unusual: There is one of the earlier DS9 episodes where one of Quark's Ferengi employees turns out to be a woman disguised as a man and falls in love with Quark.

Comment: @Philipp - that's right. I specifically mentioned `the only female that fell in love **and** married because of love`, because that is what the question is about.

Comment: Sounds like it works a lot like how it works in a lot of middle-eastern countries.

Comment: +1, but "the only female that fell in love and married because of love" *that we know about*