# What becomes of a Ferengi's wealth/possessions after death?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Since the Ferengi culture disdains acts of charity and generosity, and entrance to their version of heaven is dependent on acquiring and possessing wealth, what becomes of an individual’s possessions upon death? I can't imagine them leaving a written will that gifts them out to family or friends, but they must go somewhere, and a culture as greedy as theirs wouldn't burn them with them like the Vikings kings, or bury them with them like the Egyptian pharoahs or Chinese emperors.

Is there a mad rush to steal up the deceased's gold-pressed latinum and bank account information, fighting over command of their starships, or is there some automatic splitting up of their things based on some formula?

Comment: there is a DS9 episode that specifically addresses this, I can't recall it off the top of my head. Will look when I get a chance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Ferengi dies, it's essential that he settles his account. All debts (to other Ferengi) must be paid in full otherwise the deceased will arrive at the Divine Treasury with insufficient funds to [bribe the gatekeeper and bid on a new life](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/156264/20774). It would appear that they can choose to offer pensions and inheritances to relatives on the basis of a will.

> **ROM:** (as it sinks in) *You're going to die...*
>
> **QUARK:** *That's right. And you know what that means? **We have to settle
>   my accounts.***   (thinking out loud)   *That gives me six days to take
>   care of everything... my will... Moogie's pension... I've got to make
>   funeral arrangements... pay off my debts...*
>
> **ROM:** (worried) *That's a lot of debts, Brother.*
>
> **QUARK:** *Yeah, but half are to Hew-mons, Bajorans... a couple of
>   Klingons...*
>
> **ROM:** (continuing the list) *The Tholians, the Dosi, the Romulans, the
>   Cardassians --*
>
> **QUARK:** (cuts him off) *Forget those. **The ones I need to pay off are the
>   Ferengi debts. They're the only ones that really matter.***
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Body Parts](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/497.txt)</sup></sub>

Given that wives are [rented rather than owned](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147809/20774), family comes first when it comes to deciding how to divide up the estate.

> **ROM:** *But if he dies. Mine?*
>
> **ODO:** ***Wives serve, brothers inherit.*** Rule of Acquisition number one hundred thirty nine, if I'm not mistaken.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Necessary Evil](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/428.htm)</sup></sub>